# Database schema structure for a fantasy baseball site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a sim baseball site in Rails. The difference between sim and fantasy is that sim essentially uses the real life rosters whereas in fantasy, you draft players to your team. I've been stuck on the database design for a while now. Here's what I currently have:
[image: Database structure]

My main issue is that the `players_teams` table seems that it will be very repetitive as most players will not be on different teams. This means that there could be thousands of entires where the player is the same and the team is the same, except with a different `id`.

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean by "player is the same and the team is the same, except with a different `id`"? Also, you're missing several foreign keys in your diagram (`message.sender_id` -> `user.id`, `message.recipient_id` -> `user.id`, `players_teams.player_id` -> `players.id`, `team.user_id` -> `user.id`), and you have an inconsistent naming schema (`league`, `user`, `team` are singular, other tables are plural).

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize the names were inconsistent. Stupid mistake but Rails fixes it anyways. 

A `player` is a player on a team while a `league` has multiple teams. Each league will have the same teams with the same players until the users start trading players or signing free agents. Essentially, in the beginning (before any player transactions), for each league, there will be a `players_teams` row where the player id will be the player that is shared among all the leagues, while the team id will be unique to that league.

Comment: This means that there will be copies of the same row with the player and team the same, except the team id will be slightly different. I'm starting to realize that this is really unclear..

Comment: If you mean `(playerA_id, teamAinLeagueA_id), (playerA_id, teamAinLeagueB_id)...` Yes, that's fine. It's still the clearest and shortest way to express it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant...that's a lot clearer. I realize this is just a personal project and scalability doesn't really matter but the inefficiency really bothers me. Also, should the `players_teams` table be a join table between players, teams and league as well or is it redundant since a team belongs to a league?

Comment: The latter; you can always get to league with players->player_teams->leagues join. However, there is no inefficiency there; if a player switches teams between leagues, this is how you can track her properly. You could also model it having a transfers table instead of league team membership table, but then lookup of team membership becomes messy: disk is cheap, milliseconds are expensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate all the help

Comment: No, I'd probably go with your current setup.